# Return many interfaces in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

I am new to WCF, and I want to create an API to a DB.

The DB orm is build by EntityFramework and I wrapped all the function of get one, find many and save by and interface that each Entity must implement.

I found out that WCF service can load only one interface, but I have many interfaces and each interface is implemented by more than one class.

My main interface:

```
[DataContract]
public enum Entity
    {
        [EnumMember]
        Branch,
        [EnumMember]
        Category,
        [EnumMember]
        Client,
        [EnumMember]
        ClientInterest,
        [EnumMember]
        Condition,
        [EnumMember]
        Event,
        [EnumMember]
        EventType,
        [EnumMember]
        Floor,
        [EnumMember]
        GlobalSettings,
        [EnumMember]
        Operation,
        [EnumMember]
        Picture,
        [EnumMember]
        Price,
        [EnumMember]
        Rate,
        [EnumMember]
        RealEstate,
        [EnumMember]
        Role,
        [EnumMember]
        Sale,
        [EnumMember]
        Status,
        [EnumMember]
        User         
    }

    [DataContract]
    public enum Hierarchy
    {
        [EnumMember]
        Realtor,
        [EnumMember]
        Branch,
        [EnumMember]
        Chain,
        [EnumMember]
        NonRelevant
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBL
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Dictionary<string, string> AuthenticateUser(string username, string password);
        [OperationContract]
        string GetLoggedUserUsername();
        [OperationContract]
        string GetLoggedUserBranchName();
        [OperationContract]
        void DisconnectUser();

        [OperationContract]
        IBLManage GetBLManage(Entity entity);
        [OperationContract]
        IBLReport GetBLReport(Entity entity);
        [OperationContract]
        IBLSearch GetBLSearch(Entity entity);

        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetRoles(Dictionary<string, string> errorsDict);
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetEventTypes(Dictionary<string, string> errorsDict);
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetConditions(Dictionary<string, string> errorsDict);
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetStatuses(Dictionary<string, string> errorsDict);
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetOperations(Dictionary<string, string> errorsDict);
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetCategories(Dictionary<string, string> errorsDict);
    }
```

A sub interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBLManage
{
    [OperationContract]
    Dictionary<string, string> Save(Dictionary<string, object> entityDict, bool isNewEntity = true);

    [OperationContract]
    object GetEntity(Dictionary<string, object> entityDict, Dictionary<string, string> errorsDict);
}
```

[image: BL.jpg]

How can I make it in a single service?
Or I must create many services? (It would be about 20)
And if I create many, can I run them in the same exe?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457091/wcf-and-interfaces) about the interface return value but the link is broken, and not exactly the whole problem I have.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Are you confusing data contracts with service contracts? The former is a definition of what data you will send across the wire whereas the latter defines what you will expose. So basically you're free how to implement your service. It could be one or it  could be 20, it depends on your situation which I don't really understand. If you want to expose data from your database, why don't you consider WCF Data Services?

Comment: Or perhaps you are confusing SOAP services and interfaces? A *service* has a well-defined set of data types and operations. A .NET interface is a convenient way to define that metadata instead of using some other language. There is no such thing as a "subinterface" because there is no such thing as a "subservice"

Comment: You can "chain" multiple interfaces (via inheritance) into one interface that is then implemented by one service. I.e., `public class Service : IServiceA`, where `IServiceA` in turn inherits/implements `IServiceB`, `IServiceC`, etc.

Comment: @hbulens I mean service contracts.  In my situation a client of WCF service(s) should get an instance of class (called  LocalBL) that implements interface IBL. But after that a client should get instances of other classes - by "get" methods of LocalBL. These other classes implements different interfaces that I called "sub-interfaces" (this term is confusing, sorry). And follow that the client will use extensively the methods of these different classes.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - I didn't intend to SOAP. The term sub-interface is confusing, sorry. The intention is just for additional interfaces that implemented by about 5 classes for each interface. And I need to expose a functionality of all these classes via WCF to client. In my initial design (not WCF) I get instances of "main" class LocallBL implementing IBL interface. And with get methods of LocalBL I get instances of classes above and use their methods. Means to have functionality of whole assembly I just need to have instance of "main" class. But this doesn't work in case WCF.

Comment: @Tim - If I am not wrong, in such approach I will have a big (heavy) class that implements last (tail) interface and all the interfaces this last inherits. The initial approach in separating interfaces was to simplify program design.

Comment: @AlexAnkerok SOAP or TCP binding doesn't matter. WCF using interfaces and contracts to define the metadata. They aren't meant to be used to create an inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement more than one Interface by service, and use the same endpoint if you want.

An example:

```
public partial class MyServices
{
}

public partial class MyServices: IBL
{
   // IBL implemnetantion
}

public partial class MyServices : IBLManage
{
  // IBLManage implementation
}
```

And so on.

You can also use Inheritance, as @Tim commented.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. This is possible solution, but this have me to unite classes (services)  that are separate by initial design.